# Getting url after download dialog with iMacro

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, imacros

I'm grabbing a web page has a form inside, and after submitting the form (click on the button) download file dialog, is opened and the file will be downloaded.
In this case, I need only the final download link (I can see this link after starting the download in the downloads tab of chrome). this link doesn't exist on the page and I can't use something like the EXTRACT method.

FCI:

```
iMacros for CR v10.1.1, 'Free', CR108, Linux Manjaro.
```

**Update 1:**

I just created a sample demo, In this demo I need copy the file link, actually this link "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin".
You can see the demo here: https://custom-oakq.frb.io/

**Update 2:**
FCI added to post.

Comment: 'iMacros' (correct Spelling btw...) Tag [Wiki](/tags/imacros/info)... :idea: // I'm not sure what you want will be possible, from the Behaviour you describe, but I might have a few "things" to try, can you post the URL of the Page (or a similar Page)...? // And you *really* only want the DL Link, not the File...?

Comment: @chivracq , Sure, you can see demo here: https://custom-oakq.frb.io/ , and I need only copy the file link and not the file.

Comment: Yep, saw your Update... Could you add your FCI to your Qt, like explained in the Tag Wiki...? => `iMacros for CR v10.1.1(?), 'Free'/'PE'/'Trial'...?, CR107...?, OS...?`

Comment: @chivracq, FCI added to post.